# python nntp get headers by date range

Tags: python, nntp

How do I retrieve the newest headers or headers by date range for a particular group? end goal would be to just download the headers I need instead of downloading all the groups headers.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of standard capabilities and extensions that allow for limited retrieval of metadata and you will have to check what your servers of interest support. One relevant command is `NEWNEWS` defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977#section-7.4.2

> This command returns a list of message-ids of articles posted or
> received on the server, in the newsgroups whose names match the
> wildmat, since the specified date and time.